# asociar variables en python

Tags: python, variables

estaba viendo si podria darle a una variable el valor de otra que ya este definida.
Por ejemplo

```
ordenador="X"
jugador="O"
Jugador_turno=None
```

y queremos que Jugador del turno pase de ser ordenador a jugador cada turno. intente hacerlo con otro ejemplo pero sin resultados, seria este:

```
primernumero=1
segundonumero=2


numero=primernumero
def cambiar():
    if numero==primernumero:
        numero=segundonumero
    else:
        numero=segundonumero

for i in range(1,5):
    print(numero)
    cambiar()
```

mi resultado esperado aqui seria

```
1
2
1
2
1
```

pero da error
¿alguna idea acerca de como implementar esta idea?

Comment: "pero da un error" .. que error da ?? Hay que ver el error primero no ?

Comment: claro, disculpa, me dice que "numero" no esta definido, asi que probe a darle el valor 0 antes de ejecutar todo esto,  pero sigue diciendome que "numero" no esta definido

Comment: Al estar dentro de jna función esa variable solo existe dentro de ella, tie es que declarar la variable `numero` como global

Comment: de primeras muchas gracias, despues ¿Como puedo declarar una variable como global? Y, ¿esto mismo lo podria exportar al tema de los turnos entre jugador y ordenador, cierto?

Comment: Hice una respuesta, y di lo puede usar para lo que quieres, pero creo que sería mejor hacerlo de otra forma

Answer (score 3):

Los scope siempre son un problema para los principiantes. Las variables creadas y definidas dentro de una función con existe solo en el ámbito de la función, por lo que se crean y se destruyen dentro de la misma.

Para que puedas usar una variable definida fueradela función tendrás que cambiar su *scope*, defiendo la variable como `global`

```
primernumero=1
segundonumero=2

#declsramos como global 
global numero

numero=primernumero
def cambiar():
    global numero
    if numero==primernumero:
        numero=segundonumero
    else:
        numero=primernumero #cambiamos al primer número

for i in range(1,5):
    print(numero)
    cambiar()
```

**resultado**

```
1
2
1
2
```

Se imprimen 4 resultados por que tu `for` empieza en el 1 y termina en el 4, el 5 no es considerado